# Getting the parent div from a current div in jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I have added a dynamic class called `hello` to the last question from the form. I am trying to traverse through the DOM to get the grandparent element `.question-popup` but for some reason it does not work. Ideally once I get to `question-popup` from `hello` I want to be able to get to the `class="step-through-btn o-wrapper"` to change the text of the button the "NEXT STEP".

```js
$(".js-cme-next-question-button").click(function(){
     $(".js-test-questions-wrap .c-cme-test:last .o-overlay__question").addClass("hello");
     console.log($(".hello").closest(".question-popup"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question-popup">
     <div class="test-questions">
          <div class="count">counter</div>
          <div class="h6 u-text-grey o-overlay__question1 hello"> **hello added dynamically**
          <div class="h6 u-text-grey o-overlay__question2">
          <div class="h6 u-text-grey o-overlay__question3">
     </div>
</div>

<div class="step-through-btn o-wrapper">
     <a href="#" id="ic-next-question" class="c-button">Next question</a>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no matching `.js-cme-next-question-button` element in the code.  Nothing is ever invoking this click handler.

Comment: There's no `o-overlay__question` class. There's `o-overlay__question1`, `o-overlay__question2`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so with plain javascript. But be warned your html code isn't well structured. But mine is so:

```js
var hello = document.querySelector(".hello");
var parent = hello.closest(".question-popup");
var sibling = parent.nextElementSibling;
var button = sibling.querySelector(".c-button")
button.innerText = "NEXT STEP";
```

```html
<div class="question-popup">
  <div class="test-questions">
    <div class="count">counter</div>
    <div class="h6 u-text-grey o-overlay__question1 hello"> **hello added dynamically**</div>
    <div class="h6 u-text-grey o-overlay__question2"></div>
    <div class="h6 u-text-grey o-overlay__question3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="step-through-btn o-wrapper">
  <a href="#" id="ic-next-question" class="c-button">Next question</a>
</div>
```

Comment: how do you mean by my html is not well structured? Thanks for the solution, i tried and it does not work

Comment: You don't have closing `</div>` when it seems like you should. Compare your version with mine that does work